# Is it safe to access the popped binary tree nodes which iterative traversed by std::stack

Tags: c++, tree-traversal, stddeque, stdstack

Considering the Solution of Leetcode 94. Binary Tree Inorder Traversal. What confusing me is whether is is safe to access the node after the node being popped(`stk.pop(); res.push_back(root->val);`). I know that the underline container of std::stack is std::deque. And the `pop()` of std::stack is implemented by `pop_back()` of std::deque.

This program seems can be executed in the right way, I want to confirm,

1. It is safe to access the popped node. Whether the `pop()` release the memory allocated by `new` operator.
2. If the `pop()` reclaimed the memory, then whether the reason is that the container doesn't release storage immediately when element is popped.

Thanks!

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> inorderTraversal(TreeNode* root) {
        vector<int> res;
        stack<TreeNode*> stk;
        while (root != nullptr || !stk.empty()) {
            while (root != nullptr) {
                stk.push(root);
                root = root->left;
            }
            root = stk.top();
            stk.pop();
            res.push_back(root->val);
            root = root->right;
        }
        return res;
    }
};

作者：LeetCode-Solution
链接：https://leetcode.cn/problems/binary-tree-inorder-traversal/solution/er-cha-shu-de-zhong-xu-bian-li-by-leetcode-solutio/
```

Comment: `pop` removes a **pointer**  to the object from the stack, not the object itself. The objects pointed by the pointers are not deleted by the posted part of the code. Since you don't own the `TreeNode` objects (some LeetCode runtime stuff owns them), this does not cause memory leaks.

Comment: Erasing someone's address from your address book does not cause their home to be demolished.